# Count number of characters of every word in a string in PHP

Tags: php, string, function

I've managed to get the number of words displayed on different lines and i need the number of characters of each word next to the words separated by " - ". How can i do that?

The string is from a textarea: "i like apples but sometimes i eat bananas"

```
$words = explode(" ", $_POST['txt']);
    for ($i=0; $i<count($words); $i++){ 
        echo "<br/>" . $words[$i] . " - ";}
```

It displays :

```
i -
like -
apples -
but - 
sometimes -
i -
eat - 
bananas -
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$words = explode(" ", $_POST['txt']);

for ($i=0; $i<count($words); $i++){ 
    echo "<br/>" . $words[$i] . " - " . strlen($words[$i]);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There's no way to answer this question without sounding like a smart-arse, but... [`strlen`](http://php.net/strlen)...

Comment: There’s no way to comment on this without sounding like a pedantic critic, but this is either a “link-only answer” or a “comment”… whatever you call it, I don’t think it really validates as *“[a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)”*.

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach(explode(" ", $_POST['txt']) as $word)
    echo $word." - ".strlen($word)."<br>";
```